# Jquery disable child element of the same parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I don't want to copy any of the questions asked before, but I have hard time to solve my problem.

I have a form with few checkbox-es, some of them are hidden to trigger output when checkbox is unchecked. At the end of the page I have JQuery code, that should disable those hidden checkboxes if I enable general boxes, but this code doesn't work. **Whenever I click to any checkbox, EVERY other checkboxes become unchecked**! I think it happens because I cant aim to the only one needed element.

Maybe you didn't understand, but if you look at the code, you will find out exactly what is wrong!

```
    <form action="" method="GET" name="<?php echo $listFilter['forn_name']; ?>" id="<?php echo $listFilter['forn_name']; ?>">
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="word" id="word_checkbox" class="checkbox" <?php if($listFilter['word_status'] == 1){ ?> checked <?php } ?>/>
            <input type='hidden' value='0' name='word' class="checkbox_hidden" <?php if($listFilter['word_status'] == 0){ ?> checked <?php } ?>/>
            <label class="label" for="word_checkbox">Words</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="pron" id="pron_checkbox" class="checkbox" <?php if($listFilter['pronunciation_status'] == 1){ ?> checked <?php } ?> />
            <input type='hidden' value='0' name='pron' class="checkbox_hidden" <?php if($listFilter['pronunciation_status'] == 0){ ?> checked <?php } ?>/>
            <label class="label" for="pron_checkbox">Pronunciation</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="pos" id="pos_checkbox" class="checkbox" <?php if($listFilter['pos_status'] == 1){ ?> checked <?php } ?> />
            <input type='hidden' value='0' name='pos' class="checkbox_hidden" <?php if($listFilter['pos_status'] == 0){ ?> checked <?php } ?>/>
            <label class="label" for="pos_checkbox">Part of speech</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="meaning" id="meaning_checkbox" class="checkbox" <?php if($listFilter['meaning_status'] == 1){ ?> checked <?php } ?> />
            <input type='hidden' value='0' name='meaning' class="checkbox_hidden" <?php if($listFilter['meaning_status'] == 0){ ?> checked <?php } ?>/>
            <label class="label" for="meaning_checkbox">Meaning</label>
        </span>
        <span>
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="examples" id="examples_checkbox" class="checkbox" <?php if($listFilter['examples_status'] == 1){ ?> checked <?php } ?> />
            <input type='hidden' value='0' name='examples' class="checkbox_hidden" <?php if($listFilter['examples_status'] == 0){ ?> checked <?php } ?>/>
            <label class="label" for="examples_checkbox">Examples</label>
        </span>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#<?php echo $listFilter['forn_name']; ?> .checkbox").change(function() {
/* I reckon those codes bellow are causing problem */
                var parent = $(this).closest('span');
                if(this.checked){$(this).parent("span").children(".checkbox_hidden").prop('disabled', true);}
                document.forms.<?php echo $listFilter['forn_name']; ?>.submit();
            });
        });
        </script>
    </form>
```

Thanks to Alexander, there is a sample code on JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/TH2hh/

Comment: You use hidden input and they doesn't use `checked` property. You can change their value with `$(this).parent("span").children(".checkbox_hidden").val(1)`

Comment: @Alexander I have changed, but the result is same

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/m24w9/2/ show us an example by changing this code.

Comment: I've done it for him: http://jsfiddle.net/TH2hh/

It was my typo — you shoud pass text to the `.val()`:
`$(this).parent("span").children(".checkbox_hidden").val('1')`